# start URL rewriting in current folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, lamp

I have a website in a subdirectory of my domain (example.com/folder)

In this folder I have a .htaccess with this code

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule . index.php
```

When I do a request to this `http://www.example.com/folder/example/request` my `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is set to `/folder/example/request`.

How can I force apache to not put the `/folder/` into the request_uri-variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're dealing with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` you're already in PHP. Why not just strip `/folder` off if it's there?

Don't modify `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` directly by the way, copy it, modify it, and pass it along to whatever function needs it.

PHP is much better at manipulating strings than Apache.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And use `$_GET['url']` which will have value: `example/request`